# Apply a function to rows within a data table in R to return time of day

Tags: r

I have a data table, which I have various dates and a "value" with which I need to plot. The values are delivered in a so-called "Delivery Hour" and a "Delivery Interval". An example is below;

[image]

I can join a new colum to the right of my table, popultaed (in the first instance) with NAs using

data.table["TIME"]<-NA

[image]

This new column (shown below) needs to be populated in each row by the time of day that "value" was delivered, in excel I convert this via the function

=TIME(DELIVERY_HOUR-1, 30*(DELIVERY_INTERVAL-1),0)

So for example, with DELIVERY_HOUR =7 and DELIVERY_INTERVAL=2 this is 06:30.

I'd like to write a function that populates the TIME column row by row, here is my syntax for the function "TIME":

> TIME
>   function(x){
>   time<-(DELIVERY_HOUR-1):(30*(DELIVERY_INTERVAL-1))
>   result<-paste(time,format="%H%M")
>   return(result)
>   }

I am unsure how to ensure that corresponding row entries are picked and placed into the row entry for TIME.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you could merge it I would be most grateful. Best, A

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you allow tags to R, why not questions about R?

Comment: if you are blocked at SO, [system simply won't let question migrate](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260)

Comment: this is my very first question, I thought it was relevant to this site; there is no reason why I would be blocked at SO.

Comment: if this is the case, you can safely flag for migration (flag -> off-topic -> belongs to other site -> ...). Alternatively, you can delete here and reask at the other site

Comment: @gnat Thanks, flagged for attention.

Comment: What's with immediately assuming this user is blocked from asking questions on SO?  Chill out, it's Friday.  We do, however, need actual data and not pictures of data.  Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: @RichardScriven ["Per stats, Programmers appear to be most popular of SE sites among this category of askers..."](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6991/31260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are actually using the `data.table` in R you could do the following:

```
library(data.table)

# minimally reproducible data
dt <- data.table(date=20150202, delivery_date="02/02/2015",
                 delivery_hour = c(rep(7, 4),rep(8,4),9),
                 delivery_interval = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1))

dt[, time := paste0(delivery_hour - 1, ":", 30*delivery_interval]
dt
       date delivery_date delivery_hour delivery_interval time
1: 20150202    02/02/2015             7                 1 6:30
2: 20150202    02/02/2015             7                 1 6:30
3: 20150202    02/02/2015             7                 2 6:60
4: 20150202    02/02/2015             7                 2 6:60
5: 20150202    02/02/2015             8                 1 7:30
6: 20150202    02/02/2015             8                 1 7:30
7: 20150202    02/02/2015             8                 2 7:60
8: 20150202    02/02/2015             8                 2 7:60
9: 20150202    02/02/2015             9                 1 8:30
```

This naturally assumes the 24 hour clock time (delivery hour will not be less than 1 and not exceed 24)